# SSRS 2016 can't set credentials when using an expression based connection string

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to deploy a SSRS report to a 2016 server which uses a an API as it's data source. The URL for the API is generated dynamically via an expression which builds the query string based on a couple of report parameters.

In the past, using report manager I could set which account the API is called under.

[image]

Note that in the above screenshot the Connection string is still expression based.

However if I attempt the same thing in 2016 the connection string is wiped out.

[image]

Surely the connection string and the credentials should be independent, why has this changed in 2016 or is it a bug?

Comment: I have a similar issue with SSRS June 2017 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333311/report-manager-expression-based-connection-strings-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue in ReportServer 2017; however if you click the button 'Revert to Default' (visible in the above screenshot) the Expression based connection string will magically reappear!

Nice feature - if you find it ;-)