# Report Manager Expression-based Connection Strings Missing

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2017

I'm using an expression for a report connection string but when I upload the report to the report manager (2017 June) and save the credentials in the data source setting the text box that contains the expression gets cleared out.

The same report works fine in SSRS 2014.

I've tried using IE, Chrome and Edge and get the same behaviour.

[before save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9VRJ.png)

[after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkG1I.png)

Comment: Seems to be a similar issue posted here but for SSRS 2016
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332382/ssrs-2016-cant-set-credentials-when-using-an-expression-based-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in ReportServer 2017; however, if you click the button 'Revert to Default' (a button displayed in the same screen) the Expression based connection string will magically reappear!

Nice feature - if you find it ;-)